# "Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi Network..." is disabled in my Ubunutu 14.04!

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, network-manager

I noticed that some items in **network** section of my taskbar is disabled. When Wi-Fi adaptor is enabled and no cable connected network is available, following items are available and only **BOLD** items are enabled, other items are greyed out:

- Ethernet network
- disconnected
- Mactin
- disconnected
- **Mactin Network**
- Wi-Fi Networks
- disconnected
- **InRangeWiFiSSID1**
- **InRangeWiFiSSID2**
- **InRangeWiFiSSID3**
- **InRangeWiFiSSID4**
- **InRangeWiFiSSID5**
- **More networks >**
- Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi Network...
- Create New Wi-Fi Network...
- **VPN Connections >**
- √ Enable Networking
- √ Enable Wi-Fi
- Connection Information
- Edit Connections...

After I connect to an ethernet network, *only* following items are enabled:
 - **Auto Ethernet**
 - **Disconnect**
 - **Connection Information**

It is normal for some of above items such as *Ethernet Network* to be greyed out while I am not connected to any networks. But I expect that some of greyed out oned be enabled such as *Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi Network...*!